# How to call an event in android when activity resumes but not when activity starts

Tags: android

In android, I want to use onResume(), but I don't want it to fire when the activity is created. I want it to fire every other time it resumes. Is there such an event for that?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can use a boolean variable to check that is first run or not

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. The `onResume()` method will always be called after an `Activity` is created. Edit your question with valid code and explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. There is `onRestart()`, which behaves as you want, but as a replacement for `onStart()`, not `onResume()`. The difference between `onStart()` and `onResume()` may not be important for your situation, though, in which case you could consider `onRestart()`.